# htaccess rules are not working while works from httpd.conf

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to set some rules into my web root directory.
/var/www/html/
inside this directory i have set some rules in .htaccess file.
this file in uploaded by ftp . 
file permissions as follows.

> -rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 363 Jun 17 15:27 /var/www/html/.htaccess

file contains rules .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|captcha|images|upload_image|thumbnail1|users_images|profile_pic|js|css|fonts|font-awesome|css_admin|font_admin|font_awesome_admin|images_admin|js_admin|facebook|twitter|google|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

but when i set same rules in my httpd.conf are rules works properly.

inside httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|captcha|images|upload_image|thumbnail1|users_images|profile_pic|js|css|fonts|font-awesome|css_admin|font_admin|font_awesome_admin|images_admin|js_admin|facebook|twitter|google|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

i am unable to get what the issue with my htaccess file. 
Please assist me here .

Comment: Do you get 404 from `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes  i am getting 404

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: i have tried still getting 404

Comment: That means your have not enabled .htaccess in your Apache config.

Comment: how would i enable it ?

Comment: There are several helpful guides for that depending upon your linux flavor. Just google it.

Comment: i am on aws AMI instance

Comment: in httpd.conf - AccessFileName .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it what is have done wrong .In httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

there was 
AllowOverride None
is just replaced it with AllowOverride All.

Thank you all for helping me .

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in `htaccess`, in httpd.conf, the rules need to include the leading `/`:

For instance,

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```